# How do I set up a prompt? OBIEE12c / Oracle BI

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee

I installed a "prompt" for the "dashboard". I select only one value (1st), but it shows two values (1 and 2). Tell me, is there any error here? Or how to fix this problem? (As far as I remember, these "promt" have always worked)

Here is an example of the error:

[image]

This is how the "prompt" settings look:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a filter on your column (type_) inside your analysis to 'is prompted'? In Russian, it should look like 'вводится посредством приглашения'